# Definition of "specific gravity"

Tags: gravity, definition

I've learnt that a **specific quantity** is an extensive quantity divided by the mass. How does the definition of [**specific gravity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_gravity) fit into this scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one definition of the term "*specific quantity*"; but the qualifier "specific" is used in other ways for other terms.

For example, Wikipedia's page actually gives plenty of examples of other terms using [specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_quantity) that don't rely on mass.

Basically, the definition of "*specific quantity*" that you use would not include the term "*specific gravity*", and that's perfectly fine, specific gravity doesn't have to be a "specific quantity", you just have to know that not *every* use of "specific" means per unit mass.

In this case, [specific gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_gravity) is a term for the relative density of something compared to water.

Answer (score 0):

One way of defining specific gravity is that it is mass of a substance **divided by the mass** (= specific) of an equal volume is water.